# Passing PHP Variables to JavaScript Console Error

Tags: javascript, php, variables, console

I'm facing a bit of a roadblock in my script. I've been using the following code in my `PHP` to send variables into my `Javascript` files, for use with a price slider.

.php

```
<div class="border p-4 rounded mb-4">
    <div class="mb-4">
        <h3 class="mb-3 h6 text-uppercase text-black d-block">Price</h3>
        <div id="slider-range" class="border-primary"></div>
        <input type="text" name="text" id="amount" data-path="/<?= $foo['uri']['path']['controller']; ?>/<?= $foo['uri']['path']['method']; ?>/<?= $foo['uri']['path'][0]; ?>/<?= $foo['uri']['path'][1]; ?><?php if ($foo['uri']['path']['controller'] != 'store'): ?>/<?= $foo['uri']['path'][2]; ?>/<?= $foo['uri']['path'][3]; ?><?php endif; ?>" data-floor="<?= floor($first['min_sale_price'] / 5) * 5; ?>" data-ceil="<?= ceil($first['max_sale_price'] / 5) * 5; ?>" data-query="?<?php if (isset($foo['uri']['query']['term'][0])): ?>term=<?= urlencode($foo['uri']['query']['term'][0]); ?>&<?php endif; ?>view=<?= $foo['uri']['query']['view'][0]; ?>&sort=<?= $foo['uri']['query']['sort'][0]; ?>&show=<?= $foo['uri']['query']['show'][0]; ?>" class="form-control border-0 pl-0 bg-white" disabled="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

.js

```
const sp = document.querySelector('#amount');
var siteSliderRange = function() {
    $("#slider-range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: sp.dataset.ceil,
        values: [ sp.dataset.floor , sp.dataset.ceil ],
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val("£" + ui.values[0] + " - £" + ui.values[1]);
        },
        change: function( event, ui ) {}
    });
    $( "#slider-range" ).on( "slidechange", function( event, ui ) {
        window.location.href = sp.dataset.path + "/" + ui.values[0] + "/" + ui.values[1] + sp.dataset.query;
    });
    $("#amount").val("£" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
        " - £" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
};
siteSliderRange();
```

It works great, except the silder code doesn't appear on my homepage and I get the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataset' of null at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>`

I and `if` statement around the function, and it worked great... except Webpack removes it again.

I've considered implementing the variables directly into the Javascript file (as this would work for every scenario) - but I can't seem to get the syntax right...

I've tried to define the following variations, followed by a `console.log` to check the value, and I'm getting the following:

```
var ceil = <?= ceil($first['max_sale_price'] / 5) * 5; ?> // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
var ceil = <?php echo ceil($first['max_sale_price'] / 5) * 5; ?> // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
var ceil = "<?= ceil($first['max_sale_price'] / 5) * 5; ?>" // Prints: <?= ceil($first['max_sale_price'] / 5) * 5; ?>
```

How can I do this? The PHP variable is definitely a number, not a string.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If you are going to use `ceil` in JS, it must first be injected into your HTML (with file extension `.php` so it will run

Comment: so it is saying it can not find your element